# Get Images from media Library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have some issues to get images from media library and I would like to know if there is any option to get or automatically filter only certain images in the library.
For instance let’s say that I have images like 1.jpg , 2.jpg, 3.jpg........etc. I am getting images from media library and saving all images in isolated storage, so I want to get only certain images not all images from media library , here is my code

```
 using (MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())  
{
     PictureCollection AllScreenShot = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
     foreach (Picture picture in AllScreenShot)
     {
       using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
           {
              if (!storage.DirectoryExists("SavedImg"))
                            storage.CreateDirectory("SavedImg");

                        if (storage.FileExists("SavedImg" + "\\" + picture.Name))
                            storage.DeleteFile("SavedImg" + "\\" + picture.Name);
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = storage.CreateFile("SavedImg" + "\\" + picture.Name))
                            picture.GetImage().CopyTo(file);
            }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
var picture = media.Pictures.FirstOrLast(p => p.Name.Contains("1.jpg"));

        if (picture == null)
        {
            // 1.jpg not found
        }
        else
        {
           //1.jpg found
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeva,could you please tell me how can i get images in sequence from media library , because when i am getting images its returning randomly not in sequence.

Comment: using System.Linq;
FileInfo[] files = new     System.IO.DirectoryInfo().GetFiles(@"path\*.bmp").OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToArray()